# NSDateFormatter doesn't work

Tags: ios, date, null, return, nsdateformatter

**Hi !**

I got a string : `2012-11-07 15:22:06` and I want to do a `NSDateFormatter` on it.
I do it :

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm, MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [df dateFromString:myString]];
```

But it doesn't work, it returns "`(null)`".

Hope that somebody will help me.

Thanks

Comment: is `setDateFormat:` really so magic that it works without quotes around the argument? Also it looks like your input string is not remotely in the format you're telling the date formatter to use.

Answer (score 3):

so the format you set, is [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm, MMMM d, yyyy"];

the string myString is @"2012-11-07 15:22:06"

=> doesnt match

--- so what I gathered reading your comments on other answers:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSString *myString =  @"2012-11-07 15:22:06"; //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

    //convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:myString];
    NSLog(@"%@", myDate); //2012-01-07 14:22:06 +0000

    //output it in natural language        
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [df setLocale:usLocale];
    NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:myDate]); //Jan 7, 2012
}
}
```

Comment: @user1269586 :: from the looks of it you are trying to PARSE the date, which can be done using a dateformatter with the correct format => answer is not correct? Dont blame me blame asking the wrong thing :D

Answer (score 1):

Your format isn't even close to the string's format. Use:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` returns : `2012-11-07 15:22:06 +0000`.

Comment: @user1269586 you are confused. The dateformatter takes that string and makes it an NSDate. If you want to display that NSDate in a different format then you need to create another formatter.

Comment: Okay, so how can I do something like `7th November 2012` with `myString` here?

Comment: @user1269586[This awesome site is full of examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to get the format: 2012-11-07 15:22:06.

To get the format :7th November 2012 Use this function:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *newDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

Comment: I put exactly the same code (I put `NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myString];` instead `NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];`) and it returns "`(null)`" again...

Comment: try this: NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate: @"2012-11-07"];)

Comment: @lakesh the comment is wrong, the answer would work .. the point is he has a STRING and Wants a STRING back.. so 1)dateFromString then 2)stringFromDate